# VBA RegEx Continuous Matching

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to get a RegEx to identify when multiple names appear in succession inside a string. The names all have the same pattern of `[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*`. So, for example using the test string of: '22-A.Albert missing. Added 1-D.Barnes with 50FTE. 1-D.Barnes 99-W.Grogan is created new.' I want to match '1-D.Barnes 99-W.Grogan'... so here's what I tried:

```
Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Set regEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .pattern = "\G[0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*"
End With
Set matches = regEx.Execute(exampleStr)
```

But the matches count always come back = 0... I tried multiple iterations of adding spaces before and after the name pattern string, I tried multiple iterations of various noncapturing groups... Nothing.

Then I decided to try Microsoft's own example on how to use the continuous matching anchor '\G'... on their own [support website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) they say the pattern '\G(\d)' should match "(1)", "(3)", "(5)" in "(1)(3)(5)7"...
However when I set that example up as simply as possible:

```
Dim regEx As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim matches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Set regEx = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .pattern = "\G\(\d\)"
End With
Set matches = regEx.Execute("(1)(3)(5)[7](9)")
```

I STILL GET NOTHING! I can't even get MSDN's own example to work for me.

Comment: You are using `VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp`, not the NET regex engine. It does not support `\G` anchor as VBA regex engine is ECMA-5 standard compliant.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ahh- thank you for that, I knew it was something with the set up, any ideas on how I can use the .NET engine / would I even want to or would my time be better spent figuring another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are usin `VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp`, not the NET regex engine. It does not support `\G` anchor as VBA regex engine is ECMA-5 standard compliant.

To only match 2 or more names separated with whitespace, use

```
\d{1,2}-[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*(?:\s+\d{1,2}-[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*)+
```

Basically, it is `<SINGLE_NAME_PATTERN>(?:\s+<SINGLE_NAME_PATTERN>)+`, where `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that is used to group subpatterns, `\s+` (one or more whitespaces) and the name subpattern, and the whole group is matched 1 or more times (thanks to the `+` quantifier at the end).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jaVBBY/1). Perhaps, it is also a good idea to add word boundaries `\b` at the start and end of the regex pattern.

If you need to get them as separate entities, just split the match.